# Activate personal configuration to the config with load-file and require

Tags: config, configuration-files

I created personal my-config in .doom.d and have 'my-org-agenda` etc within it.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results output
tree ~/.doom.d  | head 
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
/home/me/.doom.d
├── config.el
├── init.el
├── my-config
│   ├── my-org-agenda.el
│   ├── my-org-babel.el
│   ├── my-org.el
│   └── my-org-note.el
├── packages.el
├── snippets

#+end_example
```

I do the following configuration:

Add `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.doom.d/my-config/")` as the first line of `config.el`

and require the appropriate personal configs

```
;;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
;;Org
;;Note taking
;;GTD agenda
;;literature programming
;;--------------------------------------------------------------------------

(require 'my-org-note)
(require 'my-org-babel)
(require 'my-org-agenda)
```

Restart emacs but got the errors:

```
    /home/me/Documents/primary.doom.d/my-config/my-org-note.el failed to provide feature ‘my-org-note’
```

What the problem with my usage of load and require?

Answer (score 1):

You should insert `(provide 'my-org-note)` at the end of your `my-org-note.el` file. (and similar for the other files).
Through this call Emacs can update the feature list with the `required` package symbol. This mechanism prevents re-evaluation of lisp code multiple times.

Have a read at [Xah's Website](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_feature_name.html) or the [official Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) for more details.